# Error opening /dev/sdf1: No such device or address (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: 16.04, boot, mount, hard-drive, udisks

My computer`s hard-drive started to give some boot-related errors after a reboot. After running the in-built diagnostics tool of my computer, it found out that, it can no longer detect the hard-drive. I have removed the hard-drive from the computer and plugged it in into a external hard-drive casing. I got this message when I tried to mount it.

> Error mounting /dev/sdf1 at /media/bogac/02c44f1d-8974-4bec-8b20-69d9d58be1fd: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdf1" "/media/bogac/02c44f1d-8974-4bec-8b20-69d9d58be1fd"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdf1: can't read superblock

If I try to benchmark the disk from the `gnome-disks` then I got the following error.

> Error opening /dev/sdf1: No such device or address (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Can you please guide me how to solve this problem ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the hard disk drive cannot be detected internally by the BIOS so is most probably dead, which is not an Ubuntu problem but a hardware one...

Answer (score 0):

Drives fail. Not frequently these days, but they do. Yours probably did. Just restore from backups!

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, my drive works on other computers so it is not a drive issue.  Seems a compatibility issue with newer ubuntu release as Seagate drive was working fine a few months ago.  Ubuntu sees it but says it cannot load.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1318038)